Partial index on timestamp unused by the query planner despite matching period in WHERE clause
I'm working with a relatively large Postgres db containing several terabytes of data. It consists of data from 5 years back. As a result all the indexes are growing and therefore reducing the query performance as well as consuming lots of storage. Current index definition (original_index) is follows:
CREATE INDEX original_index ON table1
   USING btree (key10 DESC)

I'm trying to restrict the index to only 1 year back from now and index definition (constrained_index) for that is as follows: (I removed the original_index before creating constrained_index)
CREATE INDEX constrained_index ON table1 
   USING btree (key10 DESC) 
   WHERE (key10 >= '2023-06-01 00:00:00+00'::timestamp with time zone)

I was using a specific query for both the original_index and constrained_index to see before and after execution time.
When I have only original_index, query used it for the query planner. But when I have only constrained_index, query planner does not use constrained_index. Instead it used a sequential scan on the table.
After creating constrained_index I tried running vacuum verbose analyze table1; to update the stats of the db.
It's highly appreciated if someone can explain why it is not selecting index2.
Postgres Version: 12.5
Table definitions:
CREATE TABLE table1 (
    key1 integer,
    key2 character varying(128),
    key3 character varying(64),
    key4 character varying(128),
    key5 character varying(10),
    key6 timestamp with time zone,
    key7 timestamp with time zone,
    key8 integer NOT NULL GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY
    key9 boolean NOT NULL,
    key10 timestamp with time zone
);

CREATE TABLE table2 (
    key2 integer NOT NULL GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY
    key3 timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
    key1 integer
);

CREATE TABLE table3 (
    key1 character varying(128) NOT NULL,
    key2 text
);

CREATE TABLE table4 (
    key1 character varying(64) NOT NULL,
    key2 text
);

Query:
SELECT table1.key1 AS a,
       table1.key2 AS b,
       table1.key3 AS c,
       table1.key4 AS d,
       table2.key1 AS e,
       COUNT(DISTINCT table1.key8) FILTER (WHERE table1.key5 = 'A') AS f,
       COUNT(DISTINCT table1.key8) FILTER (WHERE table1.key5 = 'B') AS g,
       COUNT(DISTINCT table1.key8) FILTER (WHERE table1.key5 = 'C') AS h,
       COUNT(DISTINCT table1.key8) FILTER (WHERE table1.key5 = 'D') AS i,
       COUNT(DISTINCT table1.key8) FILTER (WHERE table1.key5 IS NULL) AS j,
       SUM((table1.key6 - table1.key7)) AS k,
       COUNT(DISTINCT table1.key8) FILTER (WHERE table1.key9) AS l,
       COUNT(DISTINCT table1.key8) AS m
FROM table1
LEFT OUTER JOIN table3 ON (table1.key4 = table3.key1)
LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 ON (table1.key1 = table2.key2)
LEFT OUTER JOIN table4 ON (table1.key3 = table4.key1)
WHERE table1.key10 BETWEEN '2023-10-31 23:00:00+00:00' AND '2023-11-02 23:00:00+00:00'
GROUP BY 1,
         2,
         3,
         4,
         5,
         table2.key3,
         table4.key2,
         table3.key2
ORDER BY table2.key3 DESC,
         table1.key2 ASC,
         table4.key2 DESC,
         table3.key2 DESC,
         table2.key1 ASC
LIMIT 20

Output of EXPLAIN ANALYZE:
Limit  (cost=18341692.59..18341693.89 rows=20 width=159) (actual time=32149.681..32192.245 rows=20 loops=1)
  ->  GroupAggregate  (cost=18341692.59..18353658.57 rows=184092 width=159) (actual time=31749.816..31792.379 rows=20 loops=1)
        Group Key: table2.key3, table1.key2, table4.key2, table3.key2, table2.key1, table1.key1, table1.key3, table1.key4
        ->  Sort  (cost=18341692.59..18342152.82 rows=184092 width=115) (actual time=31749.763..31792.253 rows=80 loops=1)
              Sort Key: table2.key3 DESC, table1.key2, table4.key2 DESC, table3.key2 DESC, table2.key1, table1.key1, table1.key3, table1.key4
              Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 23424kB
              ->  Gather  (cost=83595.20..18314267.69 rows=184092 width=115) (actual time=31417.800..31681.660 rows=186540 loops=1)
                    Workers Planned: 2
                    Workers Launched: 2
                    ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=82595.20..18294858.49 rows=76705 width=115) (actual time=31392.569..31545.627 rows=62180 loops=3)
                          Hash Cond: ((table1.key4)::text = (table3.key1)::text)
                          ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=81113.79..18293175.70 rows=76705 width=90) (actual time=31379.926..31524.528 rows=62180 loops=3)
                                Hash Cond: ((table1.key3)::text = (table4.key1)::text)
                                ->  Parallel Hash Left Join  (cost=78481.53..18288053.08 rows=76705 width=72) (actual time=31361.889..31481.346 rows=62180 loops=3)
                                      Hash Cond: (table1.key1 = table2.key2)
                                      ->  Parallel Seq Scan on table1  (cost=0.00..18200395.20 rows=76705 width=60) (actual time=2.888..30824.027 rows=62180 loops=3)
                                            Filter: ((key10 >= '2023-10-31 23:00:00+00'::timestamp with time zone) AND (key10 "<= '2023-11-02 23:00:00+00'::timestamp with time zone))
                                            Rows Removed by Filter: 43882417
                                      ->  Parallel Hash  (cost=52397.57..52397.57 rows=1500557 width=16) (actual time=497.607..497.608 rows=1200445 loops=3)
                                            Buckets: 131072  Batches: 64  Memory Usage: 3712kB
                                            ->  Parallel Seq Scan on table2  (cost=0.00..52397.57 rows=1500557 width=16) (actual time=225.666..349.851 rows=1200445 loops=3)
                                ->  Hash  (cost=1244.45..1244.45 rows=71745 width=25) (actual time=17.720..17.721 rows=72031 loops=3)
                                      Buckets: 65536  Batches: 2  Memory Usage: 2568kB
                                      ->  Seq Scan on table4  (cost=0.00..1244.45 rows=71745 width=25) (actual time=0.019..6.313 rows=72031 loops=3)
                          ->  Hash  (cost=893.96..893.96 rows=46996 width=40) (actual time=12.367..12.368 rows=47030 loops=3)
                                Buckets: 65536  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 3865kB
                                ->  Seq Scan on table3  (cost=0.00..893.96 rows=46996 width=40) (actual time=0.017..4.731 rows=47030 loops=3)
Planning Time: 2.249 ms
JIT:
  Functions: 90
  Options: Inlining true, Optimization true, Expressions true, Deforming true
  Timing: Generation 8.216 ms, Inlining 84.266 ms, Optimization 596.840 ms, Emission 394.586 ms, Total 1083.909 ms
Execution Time: 32199.853 ms


Wed need to see EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS, SETTINGS)` output for the queries. Also, you shouldn't make a secret of your PostgreSQL version.

Best guess, because your query is covering enough records that the planner thinks it is faster to do the sequential scan then the index look up. @LaurenzAlbe's suggestion would help answer that. It might also be helpful to add the table definition to your question text.

@LaurenzAlbe updated with the information

I have no idea what  is, but you need an index on this one. Most likely  as well, but that's also not clear. This <key1>::text = (<key2>)::text is also interesting, it looks like you do some casting to text. That could destroy the usage of indexes, since it looks like that at least  is a timestamp. Not TEXT. Next time share some information, like the DDL for the tables and indexes, the query itself and a compleet query plan that matches the DDL. We can now only guess what is going on.

Giving table and column names in your CREATE statements but  then hiding them in your plan is pointless and also renders your plan useless.

Yes, the obfuscated plan makes it pretty useless. But it doesn't look like you are filtering for creator_id and document_type_id anywhere, which would explain why PostgreSQL doesn't choose either of your indexes.

Thank you all for the feedback. Now I have update the question with all the details requested (I guess) :) @FrankHeikens

@LaurenzAlbe highly appreciate if you can have a look again.

Again, your query plan and your query don't match: Your query looks for  between 2 dates, your query plan is using . So what is it? One thing that will help you, is table partitioning. That can reduce the need for an index on the timestamp. And did you change the setting for random_page_cost? Next time, don't obfuscate everything to create confusion, and use explain(analyze, verbose, buffers, settings) to get some more details about the query plan. But that only makes sense if you don't confuse everybody by changing these details...

@FrankHeikens I'm sorry for the confusion. It should be all 'key10'. Here I'm trying to avoid partitioning as we have lots of complex many to many relations at the application side. Thats why I'm trying to use the an index on the timestamp.

Okay, clear. I think I would create indexes like this: CREATE INDEX ON <table1> USING btree (<key1>,<key2>,<key3>,<key4>) WHERE (<key10> >= '2023-06-01'::timestamptz AND <key10> < '2023-07-01'::timestamptz);. And that for each month to partition the index that covers the GROUP BY for this table. Maybe you have to add a NULL condition, since this column could be NULL.

@FrankHeikens Thanks for the suggestion. But what I'm trying to achieve here is that use the existing original_index and shrink it based on the timestamp to create constrained_index. I was wandering why the same query selects original_index but not constrained_index...

You index definition still says WHERE (<key11> >= ...), which obviously does not match the condition on key10. Typo or not? And is the main table named "document" or "table1". Please get your question straight. And cut the noise. "<key1>" has no benefit over just key1 etc.

@ErwinBrandstetter Sorry for the confusion. I corrected it.

It's always best to provide the output of EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS, SETTINGS) as instructed here: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/postgresql-performance/info That would tell us (among other useful things) about unusual performance settings right away. Smells like bad server config. Not enough work_mem. Maybe discouraging settings for index usage, like random_page_cost = 4,which is typically too high, ...

Any particular reason for Postgres 12.5? Postgres 12 reaches EOL this year. More importantly, the latest point-release is 12.18. You are missing out on a lot of bug fixes. "We recommend that users always run the current minor release associated with their major version."

"I tried running vacuum verbose analyze table1;" Did you run it successfully? (VERBOSE is irrelevant.)

@ErwinBrandstetter Thanks for getting back. There is no reason to use 12.5. We have already planned for a postgres upgrade. I tried EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS, SETTINGS), but BUFFERS and SETTINGS seems not available in this particular version. I'm sure the vacuum was executed successfully. There were nothing unusual I noticed.

@Chamath Is this regular PostgreSQL, or something else just based on it, like Greenplum? The buffers should be there since 9-something and settings should be there since 12.0

@Zegarek Then I will take it back. But I was trying this on pgadmin agains the same db where it was erroring for some reason for those buffers and settings. Next time I will try to get all those info from CLI itself. Thanks for correcting me.

@Chamath: Should work in pgAdmin all the same.


It's highly appreciated if someone can explain why it is not selecting
index2.

Postgres documentation on partial indexes in example 11.2 says:

However, keep in mind that the predicate must match the conditions
used in the queries that are supposed to benefit from the index. To be
precise, a partial index can be used in a query only if the system can
recognize that the WHERE condition of the query mathematically implies
the predicate of the index. PostgreSQL does not have a sophisticated
theorem prover that can recognize mathematically equivalent
expressions that are written in different forms. (Not only is such a
general theorem prover extremely difficult to create, it would
probably be too slow to be of any real use.) The system can recognize
simple inequality implications, for example “x < 1” implies “x < 2”;
otherwise the predicate condition must exactly match part of the
query's WHERE condition or the index will not be recognized as usable.
Matching takes place at query planning time, not at run time. As a
result, parameterized query clauses do not work with a partial index.
For example a prepared query with a parameter might specify “x < ?”
which will never imply “x < 2” for all possible values of the
parameter.

Your index has a simple >= condition. Your query has BETWEEN. Yes, they logically overlap, but as you have just observed, Postgres planner is not smart enough to deduce that they are equivalent.
Try to run a query with a simple >= filter at first. Even without the second <= part and with exactly the same constant date as in the index definition and see if the planner would use the partial index. Then change the constant date in a query to a different date. Then add the second <= part.
Also, double check whether the last phrase about parameterized queries not working with the partial indexes applies to your query.
Final note, see Example 11.4 and their warning: Do Not Use Partial Indexes as a Substitute for Partitioning.

Also, in general, in practice, partial indexes are useful when they drastically decrease the number of rows included in the index. 1 out of 5 years (20%) is not really significant. Even if you make the optimizer to generate the same plan for the partial index as for the full index, I would not expect a noticeable difference in the query performance. After all, the range of dates in the query is the same, it has to read the same number of rows from the table anyway. Searching in the b-tree the starting point of the range is fast (log(N)). You would not notice the difference when N becomes 0.2*N.

My apologies: when cleaning up and reformatting the question, I introduced a typo. Before catching and fixing that just now, it was harder to see (but still somewhat visible) in the query plan that PostgreSQL does in fact translate the BETWEEN to a >= and<= here: *Filter: ((key10 >= '2023-10-31 23:00:00+00'::timestamp with time zone) AND (key10 "<= '2023-11-02 23:00:00+00'::timestamp with time zone))`*

@Zegarek, Yes, the engine converts BETWEEN into simple <= and >=, but you don't know when it happens, before the planner looks for suitable indexes or after; what representation of the query is used at which step of the query processing. Try to follow the steps from simple to complex and you'll see at what stage the optimizer fails to recognize the partial index.

"you don't know when it happens" - You do: "The rule system is located between the parser and the planner" - but I think it might even take place earlier that the query rewriter, right in the parser, the same way != gets swapped out for a <> right there, on the spot. Also, a BETWEEN x AND y
is equivalent to a >= x AND a <= y... The various variants of BETWEEN are implemented in terms of the ordinary comparison operators

What's the problem with trying these steps? "Try to run a query with a simple >= filter at first. Even without the second <= part and with exactly the same constant date as in the index definition and see if the planner would use the partial index. Then change the constant date in a query to a different date. Then add the second <= part." This is what I would have done to narrow it down.

I don't see a problem trying these, go right ahead. What I wanted to address is this: "Your index has a simple >= condition. Your query has BETWEEN. Yes, they logically overlap, but as you have just observed, Postgres planner is not smart enough to deduce that they are equivalent." I double-checked, and it turns out the swap does take place right in the parser, so both the rewriter and the planner/optimizer already get it like that.

In this case a query with >= and <= should not use the partial index as well. This should be verified by running the query. If this is verified, then the question becomes at which point the partial index is still used (if there is such a point at all). The question would become more narrow. ......... I did not realise that it was not you who asked the original question. Chamath should run these tests.

This is not the answer. I know from experience that a partial index definitely works in this constellation. At least in recent versions.

@ErwinBrandstetter, you are welcome to write a better answer. I don't have a lot of experience with Postgres. This is my guess and ideas what to check.

@VladimirBaranov Thanks for the answer. I tried modifying the query WHERE clause to have the same expression (>=) as the index. But it didn't select index2. I'm not using the index similar to the partition example. I just create one index for the recent data i want.

@Chamath, I see. I guess, it is important for the planner to have both >= and <= conditions in the WHERE of the query. If it estimates that the number of rows satisfying this range of dates is "small", it will use the index. If the number of rows is above some threshold, it will scan the table. It works this way because retrieving rows from a table via the index is significantly more difficult than reading pages of the table sequentially. Sorry, I don't know in details how Postgres works with partial indexes.

@Chamath, I would try to find an artificial configuration when the engine uses the partial index and then gradually step-by-step diverge from it to see a point when it no longer uses it. It may provide some clues at how the engine works and how to encourage it to work as you want. I may start from creating an index with the same >= AND <= conditions as in the query hoping that engine would use it. Then change the range of dates in the index definition to be broader than the query, then remove the <= condition from the index.

@Chamath, most importantly, if I find a configuration when the partial index is used (even if it is very artificial, like when range of dates in the index definition is exactly the same as the range of dates in the query), I'd measure its performance and compare its performance with a simple non-partial index. Only if there is a significant difference in performance, I'd continue with investigating the partial index path.
